# Iterar con ngFor un json con clave numero

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

¿Cómo puedo iterar con un ngFor una clave numerica? [Enlace codebeautify](http://but%20I%20don't%20know%20how%20to%20do%20it%20with%20this%20kind%20of%20JSON),

estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente pero obviamente me muestra error:

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let referencia of referencias.rows">
<div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-header">

    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        {{referencia.2}}*
    </div>
</div>
```

quiero pintar en una tarjeta el nombre

Comment: Faltan detalles para estar seguro, pero podrías poner `{{referencia[2]}}`

Comment: Gracias pablo, asi me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el enlace está roto, pero si `referencias.rows` es un objeto en lugar de 2 escribe el nombre de la clave que tiene el valor que buscas, por ejemplo: `{{referencia.name}}, {{referencia.id}}` etc

Saludos